# What kind of sieve does one use to extract meiofauna?

Tags: zoology, lab-techniques, marine-biology, methods, invertebrates

Suppose I have a core of sediment, and I want to extract the meiofauna from it, in order to study these organisms. According to the sources I could find, this involves using a very fine (e.g. 45 μm) mesh that will filter out and retain the meiofauna (as they are larger than this e.g. 45 μm that I mentioned earlier, and so, will remain on the mesh).

I have found lots of information on the mesh size, how many μm it should be, etc., but barely anything else about what kind of sieve should be used.

So now, if I want to buy a sieve to use for extracting meiofauna, I don't know anything about what it should look like, except the mesh size. What should I care for besides that, if I want to buy one? Can I just buy any laboratory sieve provided the mesh is of correct size? Or do I need some special kind of sieve to conduct such study?